# ImageView in a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a bit of a weird issue. I have an `ImageView` that is wrapped in a `NestedScrollView`.

Layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:context=".image"
  tools:showIn="@layout/image_activity">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context=".image">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:elevation="0dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.Base.PopupOverlay"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <include layout="@layout/image_content"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My issue is that on a device with 4.2.2 installed the image is flush with the toolbar (which is what I want) BUT on a device with 4.1.1 the image has some sort of padding from somewhere that creates a gap between the image and the toolbar that looks about the size of the toolbar:

See image below:

[image: Image with spacing about the image]

There is absolutely no padding or margin anywhere when it comes to this screen but for some reason on 4.1.1 devices this space is there but on newer devices there is no spacing?

Not sure whats going on here. I have tried `android:align_paddingTop="-56dp"` out of desperation but this didn't solve the issue.

P.S. I need this screen to be able to scroll as the image is quite a long image.

Comment: I believe your scroll view should have height = "match_parent". You are defining viewable size, it does not make sense to wrap_content in the direction of scroll.

Comment: i am guessing that this is not the layout that you inflate for your activity. The layout that pass in `setContentView` for your activity has a problem. Show us that?

Comment: @cyroxis no that is not a fix as I have tried that, it didn't. I tried it again for arguments sake and it still didnt work

Comment: @x10sion weather it fixes this issue or not it should be match_parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what happens is that the `ImageView` calculates its height based on the bitmap height, but because the bitmap wouldn't fit the `ImageView` it gets rescaled to fit width and centered vertically, which results in those white spaces. If you use [`setAdjustViewBounds(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds%28boolean%29) or `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` on the `ImageView`, it should adjust its height according to the scaled bitmap height. *(Watch out, on API 16 the view bounds can only be shrinked, not extended.)*